# Why must all deities visiting the realm of the living become mortal?

Tags: magic, immortality, dimensions

There are many states of being in this world, and some have managed to become immortal and gain the ability to manipulate nature at will to a certain extent. People called them deities and they are very difficult to tell apart until they exercise their divine power in public. They will sometime drop by the land of the living for an excursion to experience suffering and even dying. With exception to being banished there due to punishment, I am wondering why every deity must abandon their immortality when entering the realm of the living. The gatekeepers, which are ethereal mythical creatures, will prey on anyone who dares violate the code and will proceed to devour the suspect with extreme prejudices.

Procedure for a deity visiting the realm of the living:

Step 1: notify the higher up to get the visa

Step 2: visitor must seal their immortality into the passport
(call 1800-DEITY immediately to replace lost/stolen passport)

Step 3: now proceed to realm of the living
(visitor must produce a valid passport during check by gatekeepers)

Comment: This seems like a particularly broad question. Given how often bureaucratic policies of earth seem to be entirely arbitrary, why would it be any less arbitrary for your celestial bureaucracy?

Comment: probably because of equivalent exchange law hence to live in mortal realm you need to follow the mortal rule, hence cant be immortal in mortal realm because thats break the law and thats criminal.

Answer (score 13):

Immortality is only one of the various things that are restricted by interplanar customs. Other things include non-standard geometries, vegetables that might carry divine pestilences, various higher tier Smiting tools and any form of prophecy deemed ‘paradox inducing’.

The reason for these restrictions is simply that these things conflict with mortal reality. The fabric of the universe requires straight lines to work a certain way, so some deities have to leave behind their thousand arms (or risk looking very silly). Temporal paradoxes give the various deities in the department of inter temporal affairs waaay too much work, so they’re prohibited. Immortality (in its full blown godly form) conflicts with the laws of thermodynamics, and it’s infinitely easier to strip immortality from a god than it is to fill out the endless paperwork that comes from altering a fundamental law of the mortal universe.

All told: The paperwork is easier if deities aren’t allowed to take anything universe-shatteringly weird into the mortal plane.

Comment: +1 I think you've got it right with the line "immortality conflicts with the laws of thermodynamics".  Deities have to check their immortality at the gate because it is against the law where they are going.  No different than loosing your legal marijuana when you travel to somewhere where it is illegal, except that (hopefully) you get your immortality back when you return home.

Comment: @HenryTaylor Now I just have a mental image of a hippy god arguing with the transplanar border police about how they need their immortality 'for medicinal purposes, maan'

Answer (score 4):

They're called the "Mortal Realms" for a reason.

The so-called "Land of the Living" is actually one of the few places in your universe where death exists.  *Anyone* leaving the Land of the Living is Immortal until they return, because death *can't happen* outside them.

This isn't actually a choice that the Deities make, at least not any more than leaving your house / apartment block is a "choice" to be outside - it's impossible to have one without the other.

As for why Deities keep this information under wraps, and don't just move all of their followers out of the Mortal Realms?  Death releases power - this is then absorbed and harnessed by the Deities, like a giant battery farm.

Deities may be able to generate or suspend the conditions for death, temporarily, but this is very energy intensive, and very disruptive.  As such, the naturally-occurring "Death Zones" are valuable public resources, like a nature reserve.  No fires, no littering, no loud music, and no disrupting the death zone.  The whole "seal your immortality into the passport" is a lie, in order to discourage unauthorised experimentation.

Comment: Any human who reached Inmortality ...actually crossed the border beyond the grasp of the Reaper.

Answer (score 3):

> Why all visiting deities to the realm of the living must become mortal?

To prevent overstays.

Nobody wants a foreigner to abuse our social system by benefiting from a pension for thousands of years.

Nobody wants a foreigner wrecking havoc around just because no consequences can hit it.

Of course we don't want to look like racist or filled with bigot prejudices, so we sell it as "get a chance to experience the real life of a human! Death included!"

Comment: I mean, aside from the deities with diplomatic privileges. But nobody likes them. They keep parking illegally and then ignoring the tickets.

Answer (score 3):

Immortality is an attribute from the immortal realm, a law of nature. Now you can bring this law with you to the mortal realm but the mortal universe tends to act unpredictably if a localized law of nature is introduced. It can have no consequences at all, or all the consequences when you ravage a solar system with your mere presence. Some immortals might also be the worse for wear. The asylum of insane immortals is still trying to treat the immortals who got stuck in black holes or a perptual time curve until they found a way to get the out.

Better leave your immortality behind. Less risks to your sanity, less risks to the world you obviously want to visit for its merits.

Answer (score 1):

If a deity is sent to Mortal Land as a punishment, to suffer, refer to the Greek legend of the punishment of Prometheus. The Olympian is chained to a rock. For punishment, their powers would be limited (i.e. some sort of mystic handcuffs).

If they're just visiting of their own free will, they will retain a lot of their powers, and could easily wreak havoc (e.g. Newsflash: immortal, lightning wielding guy has just destroyed the army). If they are made mortal for the visit, they must limit what they do, or they will be killed by the mortals they are messing with.

It's a way for the Big Boss Zeus equivalent to maintain order, and ensure the mortal world continues to exist.

Comment: Oddly Enough, Zeus starting wars is the least of my concerns. I think he should be banned from the zoo....

Answer (score 1):

It was done after accident 85Xt-97. Usually immortals get bored, either things go to fast (like 5 years of war? they didn't even warmed up) or to slow (how long they need to wait for the mountain to come to them?). So they opted for the ticket-out. Just kill the body and get back to immortal lobby where, while drinking Darquiris and eating SundaePickles, you wait for you next vacations.
But unfortunately there were some immortal that opted to stay no matter what. They ammased great wealth having serious impact on mortal plane. They just raided a Romanian gold mine, hide gold in some deep cave and come back some 1500 years later to buy great tracks of land. Then they set a trust, faked mortal death and came back 500 years later to pose as their own grand-grandsons (and daughters). For example, Conquistadors? Damn immortals. 1000 years before Columb they just went to America and told people to make gold the thing. Did a few tricks, convinced they are gods (like duuuh) and just come back later to withdrawn they savings.

The worse was Egypt. The dudes (and few dudettes) get so bored they made mortals make piramids. 2000 years of ruling same place. So we had to intervene and put stop to pulling pranks on mortals and we made mortality ticket compulsory. But I herd some of them are tryig to make immortality a think there. We will need to check.